# Add Spinner Arrow Symbol to TextView

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, textview, spinner

Is there any way to add the Spinner arrow symbol and the EditText underline to the TextView which is similar to the picture below that is taken from the Whatsapp login screen.

[image]

I tried adding in this line of code into my TextView:

```
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner"
android:background="?attr/editTextBackground"
```

The underline came out but the arrow symbol did not come out.

Please advice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `drawableRight` to get the spinner icon at the right side of TextView

```
<TextView
      android:id="@+id/text_id"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:drawableRight="@drawable/spinner_icon"/>
```